# How are Final Cut Pro X workflow extensions developed? Is there another way to export/ import videos from Final Cut Pro X directly to another app?

Tags: xcode, macos, finalcut

The users of the software of the company I work in can download videos from there, then use Final Cut Pro X to process them, and then upload them. It would be great if importing and exporting videos from and to the projects can be done directly from Final Cut Pro X. From what I understand to achieve that we should use workflow extensions. Is that correct? I know that there is also the possibility to make plugins for Final Cut Pro X with FxPlug but these plugins seem to be for creating effects, and don’t seem applicable in this case, but please correct me if I’m wrong.

As far as I understand workflow extensions are extensions to macOS apps. Does someone have more information on how they are developed? For example in Xcode there is no Final Cut Pro X extension option. I requested more information from Apple like a month ago, but am still waiting for response. I cannot post any code of what I tried, because I wouldn’t know where to begin.

BTW I know about the drag and drop options between FCP and another macOS app and also the usage of Apple events and custom share destination, but the idea is though not to leave Final Cut Pro for this.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you are a developer interested in creating a workflow extension, complete this form:

developer.apple.com/contact/request/fcp-workflow-extensions/

Apple will follow up with you directly with more information about the new workflow extensions architecture.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. We tried that, but there was no response from Apple.

Comment: Have you found any alternative route? I am also interested in this and applied but I didn't get a response either

Comment: Still no response for Apple? Is this is a publicly available API or not?

Comment: I didnt get any response... over a year now waiting

Answer (score 0):

The Workflow Extensions API is now public:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/professional_video_applications/workflow_extensions

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31802041)